# div using css confused using float left and right

Tags: css, html

CSS and a div I'm trying to use float left for image and float right for the description of it.  I can't seem to align them together without disorganizing their position. I tried adjusting the text but every time the text is too much, the whole line of paragraph breaks to a new line, this is what happens.

http://postimg.org/image/b2n0g31sh/

How can I avoid this and make the image stay on it's position and the text stay to the right, and when reaches its limit it should break to a new line without disarranging itself from the position float right?  This is my code so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/93WGq/

```
 <div id="container" align="center">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="tsclogo2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="menubar">
                    <ul id="mcolor">
                        <li><a href="tdesign.html"><font color="#000000"> Home </</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href=""><font color="#000000">About Us</font></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html"><font color="#000000">Gallery</font></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html"><font color="#000000">Contact Us</font></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contentbody">
                <div id="contentbodytext">
                    <div id="divaboutusintroductionparagraph">&nbsp;&nbsp;INTRODUCTION PARAGRAPH INTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPHINTRODUCTION PARAGRAPH</div>
                    <div id="imageholder">
                        <img src="bridge.jpg" width="230" height="120" />
                        <div id="divfloatright">
                            <p>You rarely hear any entrepreneurs who succeeded in a snap. dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--closing tag for wrapper -->
        </div>
        <!--closing tag for container2 -->
    </div>
    <!--closing tag for container -->
```

Comment: Use only one `float` - for the image. The text doesn't need a float. You might align it by its parent.

Comment: Try to cleanup your fiddle a bit, also we can't see you image - hence it won't be easy to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the image and description as a section starting a new line, try something like:

```
#imageholder {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    overflow: auto;
}
#imageholder img {
    padding: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#divfloatright {
    text-align:left;
    padding-right:50px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/93WGq/5/